# gdb print <filename.c>:line number of every statement executed

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a **deterministic** (**halting**) program with **no IO**, that I want to **run with gdb** and have it print every c statement that gets executed: (say filename:line-num)

```
<main.c>:27
<main.c>:29
<foo.c>:14
// etc.
```

Is there any **reasonable** way to instrument this? I don't mind some human effort, but I can't add breakpoints in every single line of every single c file.
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT

It seems that stepping into all libc encountered functions makes the output far too verbose. Is there any way to prevent gdb from stepping into libc functions like malloc? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `step` in infinite loop till the end of the program or until you press Ctrl+C. Every `step` command will print the line number and also filename when stepping into a new function. To invoke the loop do this in gdb shell:

```
(gdb) while 1
 >step
 >end
```

Assuming you are only interested in statements executed starting from the beginning of `main` you can put all commands in a file `gdbCommands.txt`:

```
break main
run
while 1
step
end
```

and execute it with `gdb -x gdbCommands.txt --args program arg1 arg2 arg3`.

If you want to additionally skip functions in specific libc files, you can add:

```
skip -file /path/to/some/filename
```

to the commands, like that:

```
set logging on
break main
skip -file exit.c
skip -file malloc.c
skip -file strops.c
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strchr-avx2.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memchr-avx2.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr-sse2-unaligned.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S
skip -file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S
run
while 1
step
end
```

the `set logging on` command will redirect all gdb output to a file called `gdb.txt` you can later inspect.

Comment: Thanks, but gdb responds with a "The program is not being run." message. When I write run, it says "Inferior 1 (process 12422) exited normally". Is it possible that you formulate your answer as a gdb script? something like: gdb -x gdbCommands.txt --args program arg1 arg2 arg3 ...

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Great it answers my question. Is there anyway to prevent gdb from stepping to library functions like malloc.c? It's too verbose otherwise ... Ideally I would like it to only step to *.c files of my own project ... not libc functions like malloc.c ... is there anyway to do that? should I start a different thread? thanks!