# gdb - how to trace functions during execution

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I am trying hard how in gdb we can trace functions call but not able to achieve so - is there a way in GDB that when I run the executable I can print/trace functions name currently executing?

Comment: "print/trace functions name currently executing" -- this is not a useful thing to do, except for the most trivial programs. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to debug a flow and I need to understand the code of the flow - since I am not sure where to put breakpoints and starting from main times me out - so if the program during execution can just print the function names it will be best to debug

Comment: Have you googled for it? I've instantly found this blog: https://blog.0x972.info/?d=2017/02/10/08/25/23-gdb-please-set-a-breakpoint-on-all-my-functions (someone can test it, clean it up and write a proper answer)

Comment: You can try to `step` in infinite loop, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48988048/72178.

Comment: Thanks @ks1322 for the information